# Should I migrate from VisualSVN to Collabnet Subversion Edge?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, collabnet

I have just learned that Collabnet has released a single installer package containing SVN, Apache and visualVC. It has LDAP authentication and remote management among other features.
For the moment, we are running the free version of VisualSVN server, and connection to SVN is only permitted from within our network.
But our requirements are evolving : there are about 5 developers working on the repository, authenticated with LDAP, and I would like to open-up the access to the repository from the internet through SSL, and remotely manage the SVN server and repositories. Moreover, it would be great if I could plug Redmine to the SVN server.

So I was thinking of moving from VisualSVN to SVN Edge. What do you seasoned admins think about that? Is there any clear win or lose on setup/maintenance? security? Other important features?

NB. documentation for [Collabnet Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/) and [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the CollabNet Subversion Edge product for while a now.  I like it from an admin perspective.  It's super easy to use and a breeze to keep everything updated.  Since you're already using LDAP, it should make things even easier to migrate over.  And the best part of Edge, you don't have to touch your Subversion repositories.  Just tell Edge where to find them it'll bring them into view and the management console with a flick clicks.

Now your URL's to repositories might change.  Edge does have it

I'm not familiar with RedMine, but you should not have any issue hooking it up because Subversion Edge is just a bundle of Apache, Subversion, ViewVC and CollabNet's management service with all of the guess work of tying everything together already figured out for you.  If you do have problem integrating RedMine, there is a great forum provided by CollabNet specifically for Edge and the CollabNet folks do their best to help those who don't have paid support, which you can get with Subversion Edge and CollabNet for a pretty fair price and peace of mind.

You should have not issues opening up access with SSL.  Edge has full support for SSL.  The number of users you have should be no problem for Edge and Edge should allow you grow comfortably for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks! I need to check out the collabnet forums... Anyway I think I'll download and set it up.